# Pandas DataFrame moving values from rows to another rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out if is easy to make the following transformation of a DataFrame:

My current DataFrame is as follows:

```
  MY_ID UNITS         DESC
0    A1    10  DESCRIPTION
1    A1    15  DESCRIPTION
2    A1     0  DESCRIPTION
3    A1    45  DESCRIPTION
4    A2    20  DESCRIPTION
5    A2    22  DESCRIPTION
6    A2    28  DESCRIPTION
7    A2    30  DESCRIPTION
```

I have 3 columns (MY_ID, UNITS and DESC) and what I am trying to achieve is to add all unit values of the same id (MY_ID column) at the end of the description of all rows of that id.

The out I am expecting is the next:

```
  MY_ID UNITS                     DESC
0    A1    10   DESCRIPTION 10 15 0 45
1    A1    15   DESCRIPTION 10 15 0 45
2    A1     0   DESCRIPTION 10 15 0 45
3    A1    45   DESCRIPTION 10 15 0 45
4    A2    20  DESCRIPTION 20 22 28 30
5    A2    22  DESCRIPTION 20 22 28 30
6    A2    28  DESCRIPTION 20 22 28 30
7    A2    30  DESCRIPTION 20 22 28 30
```

As you can see it is about concatenating at the end of the description the whole units of that id, "10 15 0 45" for A1 and "20 22 28 30" for A2.

Is there any way to achieve this with pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try

```py
df['DESC'] = df['DESC'] + ' ' + df.astype({'UNITS': str}).groupby('MY_ID')['UNITS'].transform(' '.join)
```

```
print(df)

  MY_ID  UNITS                     DESC
0    A1     10   DESCRIPTION 10 15 0 45
1    A1     15   DESCRIPTION 10 15 0 45
2    A1      0   DESCRIPTION 10 15 0 45
3    A1     45   DESCRIPTION 10 15 0 45
4    A2     20  DESCRIPTION 20 22 28 30
5    A2     22  DESCRIPTION 20 22 28 30
6    A2     28  DESCRIPTION 20 22 28 30
7    A2     30  DESCRIPTION 20 22 28 30
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
# using groupby and transform, combine the values with a space inbetween
df['DESC']=df['DESC'] + ' '+ df.groupby('MY_ID')['UNITS'].transform(lambda x: ' '.join(x.astype(str)))
dfdf
```

```
    MY_ID   UNITS   DESC
0      A1     10    DESCRIPTION 10 15 0 45
1      A1     15    DESCRIPTION 10 15 0 45
2      A1      0    DESCRIPTION 10 15 0 45
3      A1     45    DESCRIPTION 10 15 0 45
4      A2     20    DESCRIPTION 20 22 28 30
5      A2     22    DESCRIPTION 20 22 28 30
6      A2     28    DESCRIPTION 20 22 28 30
7      A2     30    DESCRIPTION 20 22 28 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby`, `transform` and `' '.join`

```
df["DESC"].str.cat(
    df.assign(units_str=df["UNITS"].astype(str))
    .groupby("MY_ID")["units_str"]
    .transform(lambda x: " ".join(list(x))),
    sep=" ",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['new_Col'] = df['MY_ID'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(map(str,df2.loc[df2['MY_ID'] == x,'UNITS'].values)))
```